# Move routes into files in Express.js

Tags: node.js, express, organization

Say I have some routes (I have a lot more, but this should explain):

```
router.post('/post');
router.get('/post/:id');
router.get('/posts/:page?');
router.get('/search');
```

For the `/post` ones I know I could do something like

```
app.use('/post', postRoutes)
```

Where `postRoutes` is the actual post routes in another file. However, I'd like to group *all* post related routes into a `postRoutes` component (so `/post` and `/posts`), search into a search component and so on. Is there a way to do something like

```
router.use(postRoutes); // includes routes 1-3 above
router.use(searchRoutes); // only the 4th route above
```

And so on? That would let me keep the top level file much cleaner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was I was thinking about this wrong. First off, don't use singular and plural. It makes it a headache and also makes it hard for people to remember the API.

Once I used all plural I had a setup like this in my index.js file:

```
// The API routes all start with /api and we pass app here so we can have some
// sub routes inside of api
app.use('/api', require('./app/api')(app));
```

And then in my api/index.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router({ mergeParams: true });

var routeInit = function (app) {
  app.use('sessions', require('./sessions')(router));
  app.use('users', require('./users')(router));
  return router;
};

module.exports = routeInit;
```

You can see that I'm passing the router manually each time. Then finally:

```
var routeInit = function (router) {
  router.post('/blah', function (req, res, next) {
    // Do stuff
  });

  return router;
};

module.exports = routeInit;
```

This allowed me to nest routes infinitely deep.

Comment: It's not clear to me if your "finally" example is a separate file, i assume it is.  If you would have used one of your initial examples, e.g. `posts/:page?` instead of `blah` then i can be certain that's how you applied your solution, otherwise not being a node expert yet, I cant really tell how you implemented your initial question 'posts' and 'search' to make this a valid example.  I guess your index.js is what others call server.js, or app.js?

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is simple. You can even make more nesting levels. I think it is good to separate routes, especially when you have dozens of routes.
in your first file (server.js)

```
app.use(require("./allpost"));
app.use(require("./allqueries"));
```

in allpost.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = new express.Router();
router.post('/post', function (req, res) {
   //your code 
});
router.get('/post/:id', function (req, res) {
   //your code 
});
router.get('/posts/:page?', function (req, res) {
   //your code 
});
```

when you want more nesting

```
router.use(require("./deeper"));
```

or when you want use path part

```
router.use("/post2/", require("./messages/private"));
module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do that by creating a special route file. Here's an example of such file

```
module.exports = (function() {
    var express = require('express');
    var router = express.Router();

    router.get("/:id", function (request, response, next) {
        request.body.id = request.params["id"];
        // Do something ...
    });

    router.post("/someRoute", function (request, response, next) {
        // Do something ...
    });

    // And so on ...

    return router;
})();
```

Next, in you `server.js` file, include it like this

```
app.use('/post', require('./routes/postRoutes'));
```

Comment: Isn't this what @Krzysztof suggested?  I like to set `var postRoutes = require('./routes/postRoutes')` on the top, then `app.use('/post', postRoutes)` when doing it like this anyway.  looks more natural that way.